# React Native: How do I change the scroll position of a ScrollView when the element is not visible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, visibility

I have a horizontal FlatList which renders a list of vertical ScrollView cards.

When I scroll the FlatList, I would like the ScrollView cards to reset their scroll position to the top.  I do not want to reset the scroll position of the larger FlatList, instead, on each FlatList scroll, I want each individual ScrollView to scrollToStart if that ScrollView is not visible on the screen.

It would be something like this, probably using refs...

```
const onFlatlistScroll = { (scrollViewCard) => {
  if (scrollViewCard.visible !== true && scrollViewCard.scrollPositionY !== 0) {
    scrollViewCard.scrollTo({
      'x': 0,
      'y': 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  }
}};
```

I tried using the FlatList's onViewableItemsChanged and viewabilityConfig properties to tell if an individual scrollViewCard was not visible, however, I have an accessibility feature that changes the fontFamily and fontSize properties of Text elements with an onPress (to make text easier to read) and this onPress event throws an error with onViewableItemsChanged for 'on the fly changes not supported'.

I also see that the ScrollView property scrollsToTop does this when the device's StatusBar is pressed/tapped, but I am unsure of how to trigger this event with something other than an actual user tap on the StatusBar and that might be an inefficient solution to try and simulate a tap or hack into this property, but if someone knows more about this property/feature and can offer input that would be appreciated.